# Cross threading exception when trying to access object from another thread , wpf , c#

Tags: wpf, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have a wpf application.
During the running of the application, when I get to some method I fire event which performs some operations . In this event I have to access to an instance of DLL that works with Database , and it throws exception which tells that another thread owns that object. What would be the best way to handle this?

```
//this is in the main thread - in MainWindow.cs - code behind
 MyDataBaseManager DB_manager = new MyDataBaseManager(connectionString);

//event handler
 void MainWindow_MyCustomEvent(object sender, MainWindow.MyCustomEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (str1 == str2)
            {
                //getting exception when trying to perform this statement 
                DB_manager.UpdateTable(this.textBlock_MyTextBlock.Text, DateTime.Now, currenrUser);


                theNextstring = DB_manager.GetTheNextString();

                if (theNextstring != string.Empty)
                {
                    this.textBlock_theNextstring.Text = theNextstringף
                }

            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

when I compare two strings in the if statement, It doesn't throw an exception , but when I want to use DB_manager or to use the UI components , I get the  -

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Should I pass to the event a connection string and make a new instance in the object? Or there is another , better solution?

thanks...

Comment: The problem *won't* be in either of the `if` statements, if they're just comparing string variables. The problem will be in how you're fetching the strings to start with.

Comment: To my understanding I think you should not call / do database operations directly on the main thread as it is outside your application scope and you do not want to block the user thread. May be use a command pattern in your model and raise respective marshalled events for your view model which should update your view. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to do it is to use the Dispatcher.Invoke method ... 
this.textBlock_theNextstring.Dispatcher.Invoke.

Sample - 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/360540eb-d756-4434-86f9-a3449f05eb55

Comment: for the textBlock it's OK but for the database manager object what should I do?

Comment: Regarding the Database manager object - what I did was - I passed inside the events args a connection string and inside the event handler I created new instance of the Database manager and this solved my problem.....